# Run Java Selenium tests in Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm doing a POC for a Java project in an AzureDevops CI/CD pipeline. I created a Maven project that has Selenium tests (TestNG) that run against a demo website which is independent of my project. I want to run unit tests in the build pipeline and UI Selenium tests in the release pipeline.

The `Visual Studio test` task seems to be the building block that I need. I think you can differentiate between unit tests & UI tests using the 'Test files' field like **\unit*Test.dll, **\ui*Test. Unfortunately, this task is not available/compatible for Java projects.

I was able to run the Selenium tests with the Maven task and Surefire plugin during build but remember, I only want to run unit tests during build.

I actually was able to run the Selenium tests in the release pipeline via a workaround which was:

- Copy the whole project to the artifacts directory of the release during build (copy files task).
- Add a Maven task to the release pipeline
- Trigger the Selenium tests in pom.xml

Normally, you would only copy artifacts to the artifact directory so I think doing that is a huge hack.

Another problem is that Maven will build the project during build and release which is wasteful. To dial back the waste, some savvy Maven configuration might help. I was thinking about skipping compilation and resolve dependencies during release, but I don't know where to find the Maven dependencies in the DevOps ecosystem.

Am I missing something or is AzureDevops maybe not supporting Java all that well?

Comment: Have you looked into TestNG before? I believe I used this with Java + Selenium tests at one point: https://testng.org/doc/selenium.html (you'd call a command-line task to call testng) where you can have a testng file that acts as a parameters file then call the JAR file for each environment.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use testng and have testng.xml file configured. I guess the command will be something like this 'java -cp "/opt/testng-6.8.jar:bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml'. I'll give it a go. Not as streamlined as running with .NET core and Visual Studio it seems.

Comment: Yeah I would try something like that. You can probably use something like the Replace Tokens extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) or the task in Colin's extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-buildtasks) to replace values in the testng parameters file per environment which will be more dynamic. You may be able to also run the Maven task just for tests (but not familiar with how that compares to the VS Test task).

Comment: @progonkpa How was it going with this case? Did you find ways to configure it with maven/testng

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT One strategy having UI tests in the same project would be: in build a Maven task with as goal 'package' that only runs unit test with Surefire plugin. In release a Maven task that only runs UI tests with Failsafe plugin. You will have to find a way to skip Surefire/test phase during release which should be possible with profiles and variables you pass into the task. Never actually implemented though, SPOC time is over.

Comment: I am also facing one issue. How to save username and password ? It's security problem to keep in code or settings file. Is there a way i can dynamically pass from Azure key vault to maven config file?

Answer (score 2):

I do follow a method for Maven selenium tests on Azure DevOps. What I do is, in the build pipeline I build my tests in such a way that it produces a jar with all the dependencies and test classes in it. I also use testng in my approach. Next I copy my build Artifact to Artifactory. This completes the build. Now during the release I download my Artifact from Artifactory and I check the environment where i want to run and I inject the right testng file by running java -jar myfile.jar testngIT.xml. This runs my tests faster and better.

Answer (score -1):

You can try just adding a test task in your release pipeline just as in the build pipeline.
And add a copy task in the build pipeline to copy the test codes and files to the build artifacts and publish it to release pipeline.

Below steps is just for reference(in **classic view**). Hope it can be of some help.

**1, Add `copy file` task in the build pipeline to copy the all test files and all the dependent setting files to the test folder in artifacts.**

[image]

2, **Publish artifacts to release pipeline**

[image]

**3, In the release pipeline, add the task to execute the tests just like the way you do in build pipeline**

[image]

Comment: I tried you're method and for the first time I'm able to run tests in the release pipeline, tnx! I wonder if this is how we're supposed to do it, copying the whole project to the artifacts directory should raise some red flags here :) It raises other questions too, like how to run only unit & integration tests during build, while running only running UI tests during release. I think it's possible with some savvy Maven/TestNG configuration though.

Comment: If you know what the files that are needed to run the tests. You can just copy the these files only to artifacts. You can also try creating two testng.xml files for build and release repectively.

Comment: How to store user credentials in settings as not recommended to copy in plain text. Any recommendation to pass it dynamically in setting file securely ?