# Can we do .net web application in testing with Java selenium code?

Tags: java, .net, azure-devops, automated-tests

I need to configure the pipeline in AZURE Devops  but the thing is Web Application is in .Net and testing is happening in Java Selenium . Please help can we configure both the things in AZURE Devops pipeline?

As per RnD i can take the build from MSBuild for .Net and Maven for Java but how to do testing for the above scenerio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you're familiar with C#, maybe you can consider using C# Selenium code to test .net web application so that you can use official [VSTS task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) to run the Selenium test, and you can easily follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops) to configure the CI/CD process.

(A msbuild/VSbuild task to build both two projects and use VSTS task to execute the tests.)

2.Here's one **possible** direction if you do want to use `.net web app + java selenium test`: In build pipeline you should have `msbuild task` to build the web app and `maven task` to build java code.

In the end of the build pipeline you should have one [Publish Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task to publish the outputs of this build pipeline.

Now in release pipeline, instead of using VSTS task, you may use maven task([One issue I saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807346/run-java-selenium-tests-in-azure-devops-release-pipeline))/CMD/Powershell task to execute the tests. As I know the selenium tests can be executed in command-line and there're [many topics](https://www.google.com/search?q=run+java+selenium+test+from+command+line&rlz=1C1CHZL_enSG828SG828&oq=run&aqs=chrome.1.69i59l3j46j69i60j69i61j69i60j69i65.4936j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Java selenium test is used to do web UI automated tests, it doesn't care what technology the web app used.

So, in Azure DevOps pipeline, you just need to build your web app through Dotnet Core task, run it by calling dotnet run command, then build and run Java selenium test project through Maven task.